# Periodic motion executed by a dielectric in a capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Let us consider a metal clamp which is placed rigidy and is placed parallel eto the ground. Now on the both ends the plates of a capacitor are kept such that they are parallel to the ground. A dielectric is kept in between and slowly released from the clamp. Also a battery is connected to the circuit so as to always keep the voltage constant.
So the question is that we had to prove that the dielectric executes periodic motion.

> **My approach**
> We can find the change in capacitance and hence change in work done by the battery. But i am confused so as to how a restoring force could act? I s it due to the battery?